# How can I prove every integer of the form $6^{3k} + 1$ is composite, where k is a positive integer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, prime-numbers, factoring

If $6^{3k} + 1$ is factorable, then it would be easy to show that it isn't prime. I know I could also represent the formula as $6^{3k} + 1^{3k}$, but the fact that the exponent could be even or odd is giving me some difficulty.

It's easy enough when the exponent is odd as I can treat it as $6^{3k} - ({-1})^{3k}$ and use the difference of powers to factor, but this doesn't apply when the exponent is even. Is there some way I can use sum of cubes to help with it?

Comment: Maybe $6^{3k}+1=(6^k+1)(-6^k+6^{2k}+1)$

Comment: How did you derive that factorization? Was there any rule you used? I'd like to be able to understand it so I could do it on my own in future questions with similar topics

Comment: More generally $x^{2n+1}+1 = (x+1)(x^{2n}-x^{2n-1}+x^{2n-2}-\cdots +x^2-x+1)$ with $x=6^k$ and $n=1$.  Also worth being aware of $x^n-1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots +x^2+x+1)$

Comment: $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$

Comment: Okay, yup, that's totally fair. I really just didn't see that at all

Answer (score 1):

You can factorise it as suggested by the comments (which is probably the standard way to answer the question), but you had a very good idea.

Assuming $3k$ is odd, as you noted, we can write:

$$6^{3k} - (-1)^{3k} = (6+1)(6^{3k-1}- 6^{3k-2} + \cdots + 1)$$

Note that, in particular, $7 | (6^{3k} + 1)$ in this case. To derive this another way, note that if $3k$ is odd:

$$6^{3k} + 1 \equiv (-1)^{3k} + 1 \equiv 0 \text{ mod } 7$$

So what do we do if $3k$ is even? Well, note that $2 \nmid 3$, so by Bézout, $2|k$. Hence, we can consider:

$$6^{3k} + 1 = (36)^{3 \cdot \frac{k}{2}} + 1$$

If $3 \cdot \frac{k}{2}$ is odd, then we can apply exactly the same argument. We find that:

$$6^{3k} + 1 = (36)^{3 \cdot \frac{k}{2}} + 1 \equiv (-1)^{3 \cdot \frac{k}{2}}+1 \equiv 0 \text{ mod } 37$$

where you may note that we have chosen $37 = 6^2 + 1$.

By induction, we deduce that if $k = 2^{s} m $ such that $m$ is odd, then:

$$(6^{s+1} + 1) \text{ divides } (6^{3k} + 1)$$

In particular, $6^{3k} + 1$ is not prime.

**Remark**: note that we used nothing special about $6$, and we only used that $3$ is odd. Thus, the result can be generalised much more broadly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Remember that $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$. Now call $a=6^k$ and $b=1$.

Can you finish?